# java formatting text

Tags: java

I am reading 2 arrays
They are like:

```
{xxxxx, yyy, aaaaaa, rrrrrrrr}
```

and

```
{222, 44, 55, 77}
```

I want to have output as

```
xxxxx    === 222
yyy      ===  44
aaaaaa   ===  55
rrrrrrrr ===  77
```

How can I do that formatting?

I am trying this for achieve my goal

```
System.out.println(array[1] + "===" + array1[1]);
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You sure you didnt forget the second + in the exampel code? And whats weong with it? Just iterate instead of using "1" as index...

Comment: Do you know about and have read the documentation about String#printf and MessageFormat already?

Comment: Thanks Javir, can you post this as answer so that I can close this..using printf I am able to acheive this

Comment: @TheLearner IMHO stackoverflow is about covering non trivial programming problems, not about providing implementations for [Fizz Buzz programming tasks](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/02/fizzbuzz-the-programmers-stairway-to-heaven.html). BTW#1: There are questions on text formatting, specifically on columns: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519260/java-text-formatting . BTW#2 I meant [String#format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) (no such printf method in String)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String[] array = new String[]{"xxxxx", "yyy", "aaaaaa", "rrrrrrrr"};
String[] array1 = new String[]{"222", "44", "55", "77"};
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(String.format("%-9s===%4s", array[i], array1[i]));
}
```

Here is [Formatter documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] array1 = {222,44,55,77};
String[] array ={"xxxxx", "yyy", "aaaaaa", "rrrrrrrr"};

    for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
    System.out.println(array[i] + " ===== " + array1[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate on a loop.

```
String[] array = {"xxxxx","yyy","aaaaaa","rrrrrrrr"};
        String[] array1 = {" 222","44","55","77"};
        for (int i = 0; i < array1.length && i<array.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(array[i]+"==="+array1[i]);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    String array1[] = {"xxxxx","yyy","aaaaaa"};
    int[] array2[] = {222,44,55,77};
    if(array1.length==array2.length) { 
     for(int i=0; i<array1.length; i++) {
    system.out.println(array1[i]+ "==="+array2[i]);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you typed wrong your println call (one '+' is missing), if you want to tab the output, use **\t**.

Also, you'll need to use a loop to print all the array:

```
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    System.out.println(array[i] + "\t===\t" + array1[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to format your output using `printf` method..

```
     String[] array1 = {"xxxxx","yyy","aaaaaa", "zzz"};
     int[] array2 = {222 ,44 ,55 ,77};

     if(array1.length==array2.length) { 

         for(int i=0; i<array1.length; i++) {
             System.out.printf("%-7s===%4d", array1[i], array2[i]);
             System.out.println();
         }
    }
```

Using `%-7s` left justifies your `first string`.. with a width of 7
Using `%4d` right justifies your last value.. With a width of 4